# Angular 4 testing: fakeAsync with Inject

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, inject

I am trying to test service with private method which is called in constructor and contains observable:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  private booleanValue: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.obsMethod();
  }

  private obsMethod() {
    Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(() => {
      this.booleanValue = !this.booleanValue;
    });
  }

  public getBooleanValue() {
    return this.booleanValue;
  }
}
```

I prepared three specs. First with simple instance of service created with `new` operator. And it works. Second with `TestBed.get()` injection. And it works too.

When I use `inject` in `beforeEach` spec does not work. But why? Is it problem with `fakeAsync` and `inject` used at the same time? How can I use them both together?

I created working demo on plunker with service and three specs.

https://embed.plnkr.co/dw6tCGXH6LWlJuqNuQl8/

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the third spec is that the interval observable is created outside of a `fakeAsync()` function, which means it uses the real `setInterval()` function, and thus all of the assertions in the test function run well before the 5 seconds, so the last assertion testing for the changed value fails.

One way I got this to work was to separate out the initialisation of the observable into a separate `init()` method, which can then be called from inside the `fakeAsync()` function in the test to allow `tick()` to work correctly.

The [updated Plunkr is here](https://embed.plnkr.co/dw6tCGXH6LWlJuqNuQl8/).

The relevant code:

Service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  private booleanValue: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  public init() {
    this.obsMethod();
  }

  private obsMethod() {
    Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(() => {
        this.booleanValue = !this.booleanValue;
    });
  }

  public getBooleanValue() {
    return this.booleanValue;
  }
}
```

Final test:

```js
describe('Some service specs with beforeEach Inject', () => {

  let serv: SomeService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SomeService
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([SomeService], (ss) => {
    serv = ss;
  }));

  it('Third - not working spec', fakeAsync(() => {
    serv.init();
    expect(serv.getBooleanValue()).toBe(false);
    tick(5000 - 1);
    expect(serv.getBooleanValue()).toBe(false);
    tick(2);
    expect(serv.getBooleanValue()).toBe(true);
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you have changed code of application for test. I do not want to do that.

Comment: @Coosec Sure, I get that. Maybe stick with the `TestBed.get()` option, then. That way, you are instantiating the service inside the `fakeAsync()` call, but don't have to worry about its dependencies.